# I don't know how to go about a button to open a website

Tags: autohotkey

I have a couple of questions, I'm making a personal/public tool for finding and opening external tool websites really quick, in the code (Which I will provide below) I want to have buttons with the text on them with the website, the links and names of each website are in the code at the bottom of the GUI Stuffs.

I just don't know how to go about the button and text thing, nor do I know how to open a website in chrome externally I know how to do it in a batch file, but not in AHK

```
; This is an ED tools Program built to allow you to open tools with a click of a button

Gui, Show, w310 h300, Elite Dangerous Tools

; GUI Stuffs
Gui, Add, Button, w50 19 x150 y10 Beddb













;Tools

;eddb.io
eddb:


return

;-----------

;www.edsm.net
edsm:


return

;-----------

;inara.cz
inara:

return

;-----------

;coriolis.io
coriolis:

return

;-----------

;edtools.ddns.net
edtools:

return

;-----------

;edshipyard.net/
edship:

return

;-----------

GuiClose: 
ExitApp
```

I want to have a GUI with buttons on it, 6 buttons in total. 3 on each side, text saying the name of the website, whatever. but when I run it now, I get

```
Error: Invalid Option
Specifically Beddb 

Line#
006 Gui,Add,Button,w50 h19 x150 y10 Bebbd
```

Comment: try `Gui, Add, Button, w50 19 x150 y10 geddb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yane mentioned in the comment, you need a `g` before your sub-routine (label) name. (More info [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#label).) Below is a working example of your code for one of the buttons and sites. It opens the site in Firefox. You can apply this to the rest of your buttons and sites.

```
f1::
Gui , Add , Button , w50 19 x150 y10 geddb , eddb.io
Gui , Show , w310 h300 , Elite Dangerous Tools
Return

eddb:
Run , firefox.exe "eddb.io"
Return
```

The help documentation does a great job explaining all the things you can do with GUIs.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm